# How can I wait for the loop to Complete?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, asynchronous, async-await

Let me first show you what the code looks like

```
 Cart.getCompleteCart((cart)=>{
    
       let products = []; *//this Array has to be filled*

       totalPrice = cart.totalPrice;

       for(let prod of cart.products){

                Product.getProductDetails(prod.productId, productDetails => {
                    products.push({
                        product: productDetails,
                        productCount: prod.productCount
                    });
                });

      }
      console.log("Products are ->", products); *//this line is running before for loop!*
 }
```

**console.log() is running before the for loop completes** its work.

How to run "for loop" kind of in sync with the console.log() ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Also see [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Can you answer it in context of what I have done? It would be really helpful.

Comment: One option would be to use a callback, i.e. a function that you would call from within the closure after it is finished. A different option would be to use a Promise.

Comment: `products.push` happens **after** `console.log` because async

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume that `Product.getProductDetails()` is an async method (it looks like a query to an API).

`console.log()` is not "running before the `for` loop", it is just that the tasks performed by `Product.getProductDetails()` are being handled asynchronously.

Since it also seems that the `Product.getProductDetails()` method works with callbacks, one way to achieve your goal would be to promisify each call and then condensate all the promises into a single one by using `Promise.all()` method.

Something like this should do the trick:

```js
Cart.getCompleteCart((cart) => {
    const promises = [];

    for (let prod of cart.products) {
        promises.push(
            new Promise((resolve) => {
                Product.getProductDetails(prod.productId, (productDetails) => {
                    resolve({
                        product: productDetails,
                        productCount: prod.productCount
                    });
                });
            })
        );
    }

    Promise.all(promises).then((products) => {
        console.log('Products are ->', products);
    });
});
```

Or:

```js
Cart.getCompleteCart((cart) => {
    Promise.all(
        cart.products.map((prod) => {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                Product.getProductDetails(prod.productId, (productDetails) => {
                    resolve({
                        product: productDetails,
                        productCount: prod.productCount
                    });
                });
            });
        })
    ).then((products) => {
        console.log('Products are ->', products);
    });
});
```

Comment: Don't use `products.push` though, just resolve the promise with that object. `Promise.all` will fulfill with the desired result.

Comment: @Bergi You are right, I know. I just didn't want to change the code a lot to make it more didactic. I will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

`Promise.all` is designed for pretty much this exact use-case:

```js
// A dummy "Product" with a dummy "getProductDetails" implementation
// so that we can have a working test example
let Product = {
  getProductDetails: (productId, callback) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      callback({ type: 'productDetails', productId });
    }, 100 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 200));
  }
};

// This is the function you're looking for:
let getCompleteCart = async (cart) => {
  
  return Promise.all(cart.products.map(async ({ productId, productCount }) => ({
    product: await new Promise(resolve => Product.getProductDetails(productId, resolve)),
    productCount
  })));
  
}

let exampleCart = {
  products: [
    { productId: 982, productCount: 1 },
    { productId: 237, productCount: 2 },
    { productId: 647, productCount: 5 }
  ]
};
getCompleteCart(exampleCart).then(console.log);
```

**A breakdown of `getCompleteCart`:**

```
let getCompleteCart = async (cart) => {
  
  return Promise.all(cart.products.map(async ({ productId, productCount }) => ({
    product: await new Promise(resolve => Product.getProductDetails(productId, resolve)),
    productCount
  })));
  
}
```

`Promise.all` ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)) is purpose-built to wait for every promise in an Array of promises to resolve

We need to supply an Array of Promises to `Promise.all`. This means we need to convert our Array of data (`cart.products`) to an Array of Promises; `Array.protoype.map` is the perfect tool for this.

The function provided to `cart.products.map` converts every product in the cart to an Object that looks like `{ product: <product details>, productCount: <###> }`.

The tricky thing here is getting the value for the "product" property, since this value is async (returned by a callback). The following line creates a promise that resolves to the value returned by `Product.getProductDetails`, using the Promise constructor ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise)):

```
new Promise(resolve => Product.getProductDetails(productId, resolve))
```

The `await` keyword allows us to convert this promise into the future value it results in. We can assign this future value to the "product" attribute, whereas the "productCount" attribute is simply copied from the original item in the cart:

```
{
  product: await new Promise(resolve => Product.getProductDetails(productId, resolve)),
  productCount
}
```

In order to run `console.log` at the right time we need to wait for all product details to finish compiling. Fortunately this is handled internally by `getCompleteCart`. We can `console.log` at the appropriate time by waiting for `getCompleteCart` to resolve.

There are two ways to do this:

Using `Promise.prototype.then` ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)):

```
getCompleteCart(exampleCart).then(console.log);
```

Or, if we're in an `async` context we can use `await`:

```
let results = await getCompleteCart(exampleCart);
console.log(results);
```